# JQuery SyntaxError: missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, jquery

So simple, not seeing the problem.  Can someone take a look for me.  Thanks.

Error: SyntaxError: missing : after property id

```
$(document).ready({
  $('#ajax-palaceholder').load('http://localhost/devlab/users.php');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You probably wanted

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ajax-palaceholder').load('http://localhost/devlab/quedata_v2/users.php');
});
```

`.ready` takes a function as argument.

You got this `": missing after property id"` error message because `{something}` looks like an object literal but would normally be `{propertyid:propertyvalue}`.

Answer (score 0):

u need a function ()  as argument inside document.ready

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
               //--^^^^^^---here
   //your code;

})
```

or the document.ready shorhand ..

```
$(function(){
   //your code
});
```